# Trouble using events plugin

Tags: templating

I'm having trouble using the [Pixel and Tonic's Events plugin](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Events). I actually have no clue where to start on how to get it to render events in a template. I'm currently trying to pass in:

```
{% for event in craft.events.events_calendars('calendarName') %}
```

Which is obviously wrong. Could anyone explain how I understand what methods and variables those methods take for custom Element types?

Comment: Important to note (as mentioned in [Paul's answer](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2941/45)), the P&T Events plugin is **strictly an example plugin**. It was built as a demonstration of how to create custom Element Types... the plugin was never intended to be used as-is.

Comment: But if you need events... http://michaelrog.com/craftcalendars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events plugin by Pixel & Tonic is an example of how to use custom Elements if you're building your own plugin. I don't think it should be used in a production environment (but please correct me if I'm wrong).

If you want to use it, you should take a look at [the only variable](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Events/blob/master/events/variables/EventsVariable.php) for this plugin.
This variable gives you the ability to get all events, filtered by your criteria. There's no way to get all calendars, only events:

```
{% for event in craft.events.events %}

{% endfor %}
```

One other plugin you could have a look at, is [this one](http://michaelrog.com/craftcalendars/), still in private beta.

Comment: Awesome Paul! Thanks for the answer. I'm not seeing where the second (or first) craft.events.events is coming from there. Am I just missing something?

Comment: The first events is the plugin handle, the second is the events variable that provides a way to interact with the plugin's events from a template.

Comment: When I get some more rep, I'll come back and up vote these. Thanks so much for the help!